# How to disable eclipse switching to debug view while debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging

First this is NOT a question about perspectives. I already have the debugging perspective disabled while I'm debugging. My question is about the Debug view (Window -> Show view -> Other -> Debug -> Debug). This view pops up giving you information about threads running and where they are suspended and the like. My problem is that often times I find myself in need of just watching console output while stepping through code for whatever reason. My Console window is anchored in the same region of the eclipse IDE as the Debug view. If I close the debug view down there, I lose the ability to step over / into while stopped on a break point (the hotkeys don't work either, but the application still suspends right where it was when you closed the view). If I have the debug view open, every time I step over / into a method, the screen switches focus from the console back to the debug view. This is exceedingly annoying. How can I disable this?

Edit - I just did some testing, and the Debug view receives focus over anything else that's anchored in the same region as it. Regardless of what the other tabs purpose may be. There might be some exceptions, but surely there is a way to disable this someplace...

I also noticed that it doesn't switch to debug view with every step, in my case it switches when something is written to SDT Out.

One last Edit - I found a work around, it doesn't answer the question I asked but does solve my particular situation. Under Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console there are two check boxes for show when program writes to standard out / standard error. If I check those, eclipse will first switch to the Debug view, then immediately switch back to the console.

Comment: Your path to get the the debug view seems slightly off from what I have.  Which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Dev

Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

Apologies, should have included that in the OP.

Comment: @CasualT I had mistyped the path to the view in the OP. I edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Anchor the Console in a different part stack so you can see its output along with the Debug view and the editor pane.

The only reason the step actions know which thread to operate on is because it's selected in the Debug view and the Debug view has focus.

Comment: I understand now. I created a multithreaded app and paused on different threads, and learned how this behaves. I still think its weird that the debug view needs to be anchored someplace, and that it gains focus in annoying ways, but it does make sense.

Comment: This helped make my debugging of multi-thread applications much better. Thanks you for the post.

Answer (score 9):

Eclipse's Preferences under Run/Debug? There are two useful options you can change;

- Activate the workbench when a breakpoint is hit
- Activate the debug view when a breakpoint is hit

hopefully it will solve your problem. goodlouck

Comment: While this answer solves these issue, this prevented my breakpoints from hitting in Eclipse Oxygen. For me, @nitind was correct in stating that the Debug viewneeds to be in focus, so I ended up reverting back to letting Eclipse switch to the Debug view as it pleases.